# .removeClass('visible').addClass('invisible'); vs. .hide() or .show()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am an intern and I came across some code like the above in the title.

```
$(".someClass").removeClass('visible').addClass('invisible');
$(".someClass").removeClass('invisible').addClass('visible');
//there are css classes for this that set display to none etc.
```

It is buggy and I was charged with changing some UI stuff so I thought I would replace the above with `.hide()` and `.show()` correspondingly. The bugs have more or less disappeared. What are the advantages of one way over the other? In this case the latter appears to have worked better, so why would you implement it the first way?

#### EDIT:

I am just trying to show and hide page elements depending on what page options have been chosen. Which option is best practice?

Comment: By "chaining" the functions you are having a performance hit. Also, you shouldn't have two dots ".." between functions.

Comment: As you have discovered first way is wrong. Someone has taken a bad decision of writing their own CSS class for hiding/showing the element. But the complex interaction of CSS overridings can make it behave inconsistently. If you want to hide something call `hide`!

Comment: @RaviH That's not great advice. CSS is for managing the visual styling of elements, not JavaScript.

Comment: @meagar What I said is the right advice for this question. Please read the answers below.

Comment: @RaviH I have, your advice is still bad. Usually, if you want to hide an element, using `.hide()` indicates a problem with you've architected your system. I would say `.hide()` should *not* be used in most non-trivial cases. Using `.hide()` and `.slideDown()` and such functions instead of the equivalent CSS lead to the ugly spaghetti soup that jQuery is somewhat famous for.

Comment: @meagar As experienced by the author of this question, the approach you are suggesting is wide open for very tough to trace bugs. Using `hide()` and `.show()` will not allow scope for such problems. Please excuse me  if you still think your approach is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $(selector).hide();
```

and

```
 $(selector).show();
```

simply adds

```
 style="display:none;"
```

and

```
 style="display:block;"
```

respectively to the selector.

When you add and remove classes, you can add a myriad of styles and manage them in your style sheet.

Personally, when I'm simply showing or hiding a selector via jQuery, I use

```
 show();
 hide();
```

or

```
 toggle();
```

Comment: `$(selector).show();` does not simply add `style="display:block;"` to an element. It will instead lookup the normal CSS display value for that element and use that.

Comment: Indeed `$().show()` is smarter than simply adding `style="display:block;"` however, it is slower than `addClass('hidden')`/`removeClass('hidden)` (https://jsperf.com/jquery-hide-and-show-vs-addclass-and-removeclass).

Answer (score 2):

.removeClass('visible').addClass('invisible'); - gives an element a class, that can have one or more properties, in this case it's probably display: none and display: block (or table, or.. something else, you can't know)

.hide() and .show() - does not mess with the element's classes, it changes its style directly with display: none and display: block (or whatever type of visibility it had before)

It depends on the situation which to use. You have more control when you add and remove classes though, but probably less performance.

EDIT: Holy Moly, the comment dude is right, I have been living in a lie. I wonder if I experienced a bug or something back in the day when I was 100% sure it did not restore its default visibility, but assign "block" to it by force.

jquery site says:

> This is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "block"),
>   except that the display property is restored to whatever it was
>   initially. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden
>   and shown, it will once again be displayed inline.

Comment: `.show()` **does not** blindly add `display: block` – it would be very buggy if it did. It resets the element to its default display type – which could certainly be `table`, `inline-block`, etc. See http://api.jquery.com/show/ ("if an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline") or https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js#L152

Answer (score 1):

Hide and show methods are using style inline code

```
style="display:block"
style="display:none"
```

And show method always add "display:block". If you need use for example display:inline-block - you should use your classes, if not - you can use show and hide.

Also instead of combination show and hide you can use method [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: `.show()` **does not** blindly add `display: block` – it would be very buggy if it did. It resets the element to its default display type – which could certainly be inline-block. See http://api.jquery.com/show ("if an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline") or http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js#L152 or http://jsfiddle.net/Lb6Vf/

Comment: This is now a bigger problem if you use css flex!

Answer (score 1):

Generally hiding and showing elements via CSS is a good practice, but this is a bad way of going about it.

If you're going to hide and show elements by toggling CSS classes, do so by toggling a *semantic* class on the highest level element that makes sense. Move a single higher-level element between known states like `.showing-post` or `.creating-comment`, and let that trickle down to all its children elements, hiding some elements, resizing others, etc etc.

Don't add classes like `invisible` or `visible` to the elements themselves, that's drastically over-complicated and a reinvention of the already available `.show()` and `.hide()`.